# Normalizing vector produces nan in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm getting some strange behavior from scipy/numpy that I suspect is a bug but someone may know better?  I've got a pair of long arrays which I'm breaking into frames which are of length 2-4 for debugging purposes.  I want to normalize each pair of frames and take the dot product.  The code that does it (with some debugging output) is:

```
   tf = numpy.copy(t_frame) / norm(t_frame)
   pf = numpy.copy(p_frame) / norm(p_frame)
   print "OPF:"
   print p_frame
   print "PF: "
   print pf
   print "TF norm is: " + str(norm(tf))
   print "PF norm is: " + str(norm(pf))
   print numpy.dot(tf, pf)
   return numpy.dot(tf, pf)
```

This does what I'd expect for a while (specifically giving a norm of 1 for tf and pf) but then I start to see lines like this:

> OPF:
>
> [ -91 -119 -137 -132]
>
> PF:
>
> [ nan  nan  nan  nan]

What??  This can be normalized fine in a new Python window:

```
>>> p = [ -91, -119, -137, -132] 
>>> p / norm(p)
array([-0.37580532, -0.49143773, -0.56577285, -0.54512421])
```

For what it's worth, I've tried `numpy.linalg.norm`, `scipy.linalg.norm`, and defining a function to return the square root of the dot product.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the suggestions!  I tried switching the dtype to float128 and am sadly getting similar behavior.  I'm actually inclined to believe that it's a bug in *Python* rather than numpy at this point:

1. If it were a straightforward overflow issue, it seems like I'd get it consistently with a given list.  But the norm computes fine if I do it in a new python session.
2. I tried rolling my own:

   ```
   def norm(v):
      return (  sum(numpy.array(v)*numpy.array(v)))**(0.5)
   ```

   This only uses numpy  to represent the arrays.  I still get the same issue, but *later* in the data set (and no runtime warnings).  It's doing about 37000 of these computations.
3. I'm actually computing the norm on two frames, a t_frame and a p_frame.  The computation of one chokes if and only if the computation for the other one does.

Put together, I think there's some weird buffer overflow somewhere in the bowels of Python (2.7.9)???  I ultimately need these computations to be fast as well; so I'm thinking of just switching over to Cython for that computation.

Update 2:
I tried really rolling my own:

```
def norm(v):
  sum = float(0)
  for i in range(len(v)):
    sum += v[i]**2
  return sum**(0.5)
```

and the problem disappears.  So I would guess that it *is* a bug in numpy (1.9.0 on Gentoo Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in numpy.  I can reproduce the problem if the data type of the array is `np.int16`:

```
In [1]: np.__version__
Out[1]: '1.9.2'

In [2]: x = np.array([ -91, -119, -137, -132], dtype=np.int16)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([ -91, -119, -137, -132], dtype=int16)

In [4]: np.linalg.norm(x)
/Users/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:2061: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return sqrt(sqnorm)
Out[4]: nan
```

The problem also occurs in the master branch of the development version of numpy.  I created an issue here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6128

If `p_frame` is, in fact, a 16 bit integer array, a simple work-around is something like:

```
x = np.asarray(p_frame, dtype=np.float64)
pf = x / norm(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following one of Warren's links, I get this warning:

```
In [1016]: np.linalg.norm(100000*np.ones(2).astype('int16'))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:2051: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return sqrt(add.reduce((x.conj() * x).real, axis=None))
```

For this `x2`, the inner expression is negative - the result of overflow in a small dtype.

```
In [1040]: x2=100000*np.ones(2).astype('int16')
In [1041]: np.add.reduce((x2.conj()*x2).real,axis=None)
Out[1041]: -1474836480
```

similarly with an `x1`:

```
In [1042]: x1
Out[1042]: array([ -9100, -11900, -13700, -13200], dtype=int16)
In [1043]: np.add.reduce((x1.conj()*x1).real,axis=None)
Out[1043]: -66128
```

If the sum of the 'dot' becomes too large for the `dtype`, it can be negative, producing a `nan` when passed through `sqrt`.

(I'm using 1.8.2 and 1.9.0 under linux).