# How to prevent Normalization Formula to produce NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, normalization

While trying to normalize my data with the following formula:

```
normalized_df=(df-df.mean())/df.std()
```

Some of the values become NaN. I think the only reason it can become NaN is if the stanard deviation is equal to zero (Divided by 0). This is very unlikely as that would mean all the values must have the same value.

**Why does this happen then? How to avoid it?**

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685156/normalizing-vector-produces-nan-in-numpy) that suggest it might be a bug!

Comment: Shouldn't you be applying this column-wise?

Comment: That's the default for `std` if you don't explicitly specify the axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any extra input `std` will give the standard deviation over the columns. So the first obvious thing to check is what the columns look like for which you get NaN.

It can have more than one reason. Either, as you say, because their std is 0. Or because any of the columns entries is NaN.

So to go bug-hunting, check what's going on in the particular column. Explicitly compute mean and std for yourself and see what's going on. And check if any of the entries in the column is already NaN. I can't imagine that the numpy bug hasn't been fixed for over 4 years.

Comment: You are right, the bug was that I had a column with only two 1's and thousands of 0's. So when I applied my 'removing outliers' function all of that column became 0's. Great thinking!